# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)sin^2(nx)dx$ considering $\int g(x)dx = 1$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\sin^2(nx)\,dx$ considering $\int g(x)\,dx = 1$, and $g \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

My reasoning is the following: take $nx = t$, then we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int g(x) \sin^2(nx)\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int  \frac{1}{n}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\sin^2x\,dx.$$

If $g$ is continuous, then the dominated convergence theorem says that the integral should be zero. If $g$ is not continuous, take $f$ continuous such that $\|f-g\| \leq \varepsilon$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \frac{1}{n}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\sin^2x\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \left(\frac{1}{n}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) - \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)\sin^2x\,dx.$$

I am not sure why $\int g(x)\,dx = 1$ is needed here.

Comment: But having $g \in L^1$ is enough for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add more: the limit depends on $\int g(x)\, dx$; it's not necessarily zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity 
$$\sin^2(nx) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\cos(2nx)$$
we write 
$$\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\sin^2(nx)\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\, dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\cos(2nx)\, dx$$Since $g\in L^1$ the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma gives $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\cos(2nx)\, dx = 0$$Therefore$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\sin^2(nx)\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\, dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Would you mind pointing out where I am wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: @penny the dominated convergence theorem cannot be applied directly when $g$ is continuous, because $g$ is not necessarily bounded on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, the bound has to be independent of $n$. Thanks